# SQL statement to select an object that has multiple attributes in the same column

Tags: sql

If I were given the following table **ATHELTE**

```
PLAYER_NAME    SPORT_PLAYED  YEAR_PLAYED
----------     -----------   ------------
BOB            Basketball    2010
BOB            Basketball    2011
BOB            Basketball    2012
JOHN           Basketball    2010
JOHN           Soccer        2011
...
```

and I want to find a player who has played the same sports across multiple years (in this case it should return BOB since he played basketball for three years) what is the statement to reach the name?

Below is my attempt

```
SELECT DISTINCT PLAYER_NAME
FROM ATHLETE
HAVING count(YEAR_PLAYED > 1)
```

But for some reason it returns an empty set

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: yes, sorry ill add that in! totally forgot about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select player_name, sport_played, count(*) 
from athlete group by player_name, sport_played having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Two questions, why are we counting all ( count(*) ) and not count(YEAR_PLAYED), and how would the logic change if i toss in another row with BOB, TENNIS, 2010 ?

Comment: @user3277633 I fixed my query AGAIN (SO reformatted it!) - try again.  And try tossing in that row and see what happens - it should work just the same.

Comment: another thing popped up. it appears that I must always have a GROUP BY if i want to execute the HAVING clause. What if I want to also see all the year_played by bob? I tried simply adding year_played to the SELECT part, but it returns a no schema found error

Comment: Then what you need is a subquery.  There's a lot you can do with sql. select * from athlete where player_name in 
(select player_name from athlete group by player_name, sport_played having count(year_played) > 1)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

Comment: Count(*) counts all rows, count(columnname) counts only rows where columnname is not null.